# preg_math_all | PHP | регулярные выражение | строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка: 
`[HOST]127.0.0.1[/HOST][LOGIN]root[/LOGIN]`
Дальше продолжать смысла нет.

Имеется строка, необходимо из вот этих `самописных тегов`, взять значения.

Пробовал `preg_match_all` не получалось ничего.

Кто знает как это можно организовать???

В интернете вообще нету информации по preg_match есть только примеры, но объяснений как это работает - нету. Поэтому и сложно в понимании.

Comment: набросал пример, изучайте: [смотреть демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35d96d231d5a8bbcfc89df0651db851d78638568)

Comment: не помогло, выводится совсем не то

Comment: _необходимо из вот этих самописных тегов, взять значения_ вот эти значения там и выводятся. Или куда вы смотрите? Там массив, в массиве две группы - первая, содержит полное соответствие с шаблоном, вторая - только 127.0.0.1 и только root. В идеале надо пропустить полученный результат через любой фильтр, чтоб удалить пустые элементы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В документации особо не расписано, как именно писать регулярные выражение, потому что они одинаковые везде, не только в пхп. Поэтому лишь рассказывает о функциях работы с ними, предполагается что синтаксис самих регулярок вы должны знать.

Можете попробовать следующий вариант кода:

```
$text = "[HOST]127.0.0.1[/HOST][LOGIN]root[/LOGIN]";

preg_match_all('/\[(?<tag>\w+)\](?<value>.*?)\[\/\1\]/iu', $text, $matches);


$result = array_combine($matches['tag'], $matches['value']);
print_r($result);
```

результатом работы будет

```
Array (
   [HOST] => 127.0.0.1
   [LOGIN] => root
)
```

Возьмем все выражение целиком: `\[(?<tag>\w+)\](?<value>.*?)\[\/\1\]`
Возможно, вы знаете что группы соотвествий заключаются в круглые скобки. Данные группы можно именовать, и имена групп задаются с помощью конструкции как тут `?<tag>` или `?<value>`. Это будут ключи соответствий в результирующем массиве `$matches`.

Опустим эти имена, и наше выражение будет следующим `\[(\w+)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]`, что становится куда короче.
Первая часть `\[(\w+)\]`. Поскольку символы `[]` имеют в руглярках свое знание, то они экранированы. Между ними остается группа `(\w+)`, где скобки обозначают саму группу захвата, а `\w+` соответствуют 1 и более символов из набора `a-z0-9_`.

В конце регулякри присутствует `\[\/\1\]`, здесь помимо `[]` также экранируется и закрывающий слэш тэга `/`. Далее имеется `\1`, это называется обратной ссылкой и говорит о том, что текст должн соответствовать первой группе захвата, то есть тексту открывающего тэга.

Ну и наконец в середине `(.*?)`, здесь также скобки означают группу захвата. Точка `.` обозначает любой символ. `*` обозначает что число символов от 0 и более. Знак вопроса `?` это модификатор *жадности* поиска, с ним результат будет содержать минимальную строку.

сама регулярка ограничивается символами `/` (или другими, т.е. `/текст регулярки/`)  и имеет модификаторы `iu`(регистронезависимый поиск с учетом юникода).

Answer (score 5):

Для разбора строк с известным заранее форматом можно использовать функцию [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sscanf.php) (это такой, своеобразный, `printf` наоборот)

Т.е. в вашем случае так

```
sscanf($input, "[HOST]%s[/HOST][LOGIN]%s[/LOGIN]", $host, $login);
```

Соответственно в `$host` и `$login` будут помещены значения соответствующих `%s`.

PS У нее есть некоторые нюансы использования, так что рекомендую тщательно изучить документацию в части правил разбора модификаторов

Comment: спасибо, узнал для себя кое-что новое!!!